# HDWalletProvider & truffleconfig: 'truffle migrate' will compile but not do anything else

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nodejs, truffle-migration, solc

I am trying to build a React app with Truffle. Firstly, my file structure is like so, with root_dir being the project root directory:

```
root_dir/node_modules/src/libs/truffle
```

All of truffle's files, including contracts, are in that truffle directory. Everything works normally if I migrate to a local ganache rpc, but if I try to use HDWalletProvider locally or with Ropsten, the following happens:

```
usr@machine:~/.../root_dir/$ npm run migrate

> project@0.1.0 migrate /home/.../root_dir/
> cd ./src/libs/truffle/ && truffle migrate --network development --reset       
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

usr@machine:~/.../root_dir/$
```

My truffle-config looks like this:

```
require("./../../../node_modules/dotenv").config();
const HDWalletProvider = require("./../../../node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider");

module.exports = {
    compilers: {
        solc: { 
            version: "0.5.6",
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true,
                runs: 200,
            }
        }
    },
    networks: {
        development: {
            provider: function() { return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, "localhost:8545") },
            network_id: "*",
        },
        ropsten: {
            provider: function() { return  new HDWalletProvider(
                process.env.MNEMONIC,
                'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}'
            )},
            gasPrice: 4000000000,
            network_id: 3,
        }
    }, 
}
```

I am on node 10.15.3, truffle 5.0.8, and solc 0.5.6. I cannot figure out how to get past this issue as there are no throws & debug output. Thanks!

Comment: I tried putting all of the truffle files into root_dir and the behavior is unchanged

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with your folder permissions. Did you by any chance run `sudo npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider`? (`sudo` is the culprit here)

I was struggling with exactly the same issue, so out of frustration, I made a new project folder, run `truffle init` and `npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider`, copied my contracts and configuration files to the new folder, and the deployment to Ropsten worked just fine.